# How to search our Outlook GAL for several thousand addresses to see if they are present without scripting

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, search

I have a list of a few thousand user email addresses that I need to confirm if they exist in our GAL. Rather than search one at a time, I need to find a way, preferably without having to run a script (our policy will block this) to do so.

It turns out that just popping a big block of email addresses into the To; field and clicking 'Check Names' will not work, since that resolves addresses in Active Directory regardless of their presence in the GAL. I put in some known missing addresses and they resolved fine, unfortunately.

I can't just export our hundreds of thousands of addresses into a csv file to do a VLOOKUP.  Our system policies will not let me use PowerShell scripts (I wish I could do this).

Ideally I'd be able to tell the Check Names feature to reject names not in the GAL somehow. If it could be set temporarily to ignore AD that would give us what we need.

Any ideas? Or am I stuck doing one name at a time?

Comment: This can be done using VBA. I can give pointers, but you'll have to go the route yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the "Check Names" feature in Outlook as shown in the below figure?

[image]

If so, I'm afraid you can only check it manually one by one without script.